# How to stop Surface from passing through clicks

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a FAB that when clicked expands upwards to show multiple options. I am trying to add an overlay so that the screen has a slightly darker tint to focus on the FAB when expanded. Overlay and transparency work fine; however, clicks all pass through the surface to click the buttons on display which means that I can't use those clicks to collapse the FAB.

As a minimal example, I want the amount to increase by ten even when I directly click the Button.

[image: Example]

Here's the code for the example above:

```kotlin
MaterialTheme {
    var amount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        onClick = { amount += 10 }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(20.dp)
                .width(50.dp)
        ) {
            Button(onClick = { amount += 1 }) {
                Text(text = "Amount: $amount")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If that's not possible, I'd love any ideas on how to make the FAB collapse when clicked outside.

Comment: You mean that you wanna touches to pass though the button as if it was not a button but a simple text? If so, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877700/how-can-i-detect-a-click-with-the-view-behind-a-jetpack-compose-button/68878910#68878910)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov That seems like what I want - thank you!