# prevent button click from being recognized on underlying composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using Jetpack Compose and have a composable with a video player.  When you tap the screen I have a listener that pauses the video.

On the top of the screen I have a top AppBar with an icon button.

When I tap the icon button the onClick fires but then the click is also consumed by the underlying composable, in my case the video player, so the video is also paused.

Question:

How do I make the icon button be the only composable that consumes the click? I do not want any other view to detect the click.

I am new to Jetpack Compose and cannot find any information on how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and provide a [mcve] showing your video player and your app bar.

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877700/how-can-i-detect-a-click-with-the-view-behind-a-jetpack-compose-button